# Appending into a dictionary within a loop - strange behavior

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, append

This might sound banal but it has being a pain.
So I wrote code that parses lines. The .txt file has a line which match my re.match and a line which doesnt.

```
cat file.txt
00.00.00 :  Blabla
x
```

In this case I treat checking the first letter "x".

```
def parser():
path = "file.txt"
with open (path, 'r+') as file:
msg = {}
list = []
start = 0
   lines = file.readlines() 
   for i in range (0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]

        if re.match('MY RULES', line) is not None:
                field['date'] = line[:8]
                msg['msg'] = line[start + 2:]
                print msg
                if line.startswith('x'):
                    msg['msg'] += line

        list.append(msg)

    print chat
```

OUTPUT for 2 lines

```
{'date': '0.0.00', 'msg': 'BlaBla'}
{'msg': 'x'}
```

The problem is I cant append the second  dict message['msg'] to the last message, if starts with "x".

The expected output is:

```
 {'date': '0.0.00', 'msg': 'BlaBlax'}
```

I tried using the variant, for changing the last appended chat:

```
        else:

        list[len(list) - 1]['msg'] += + line
```

but then I get the error:
IndexError: list index out of range

I also tried using next(infile) to predict the next line, but then it output every other line.

How would you trick a nested loop to append a dict entry?

Cheers

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Currently the handling of lines with "x" is only reached, when the match was successful. This mismatches your expected result.

Comment: maybe        ` if re.match('MY RULES', line) is not None:` this is not letting it pass to the line with adds `x` as `msg`

Comment: do you always have a pair `(date, message)`? In that case you could read the whole file and do `str.split(':')`

Comment: @guidot: Thats the point. If I indent f on the same level, it will output msg['msg'] as a single value. Ex. {'date': '0.0.00', 'msg': 'BlaBla'}
{'msg': 'x'} ------- I want to append it to the previous dictionary, where it matched.

Comment: @harshil9968: commenting "is not None" would affect the result.

Comment: @RandomDude: well mostly. All lines should have {date : msg} but the ones which dont (the x case), should be check by the second if and appended to the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use `list` as a name for a variable it is builtin keyword and you are shadowing it.

Secondly if I understand correctly you would like to append the last result.

Here:

```
if re.match('MY RULES', line) is not None:
                field['date'] = line[:8]
                msg['msg'] = line[start + 2:]
                print msg
                if line.startswith('x'):
                    msg['msg'] += line
```

You are analyzing the same line and this `msg['msg'] = line[start + 2:]` in the next iteration overwrites your key `msg` in dictionary `msg` and clear the previous value. So this code

```
 field['date'] = line[:8]
 msg['msg'] = line[start + 2:]
 print msg
```

Always gets executed even for a simple `x` in your input file and clears the previous values under the key `msg`

If you would like it to work you need if else although I would recommend storing intermediate values it in a different way then in locally scoped variable.

**Full example with code fix:**

```
def parser():
    path = "file.txt"
    with open(path, 'r+') as file:
        msg = {}
        chat = []
        start = 0
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            line = lines[i]

            if True:
                if line.startswith('x'):
                    msg['msg'] += line
                else:
                    msg['date'] = line[:8]
                    msg['msg'] = line[12:]
                    chat.append(msg)


        print(chat)

parser()
```

Result:

```
[{'date': '00.00.00', 'msg': 'Blabla\nx'}]
```

Assuming that the line `if re.match('MY RULES', line) is not None:`
is `True` for all the lines in the file that is:

```
00.00.00 :  Blabla
x
```

Comment: I tried that but still doesnt work. Running this code, it appends the first line to the first line.

Comment: Well then check re.match() rules because this code works on my rig I will post the result in an edit.

Comment: crazy... so it has definitely to do with the rules, because  I have the same code as you only with the rules. Let me try

Comment: Sorry there was a small mistake I rewrote it. Notice that in place of you re.match I changed to if True for simplicity

Comment: Copy paste the edited example, take note I changed some variable names. The magic line[8:] line[12:] is to conform to the format of input file you provided

Comment: I noticed that. It output only  [{'date': '00.00.00', 'msg': '.00.00 :  Blabla\nx\n'}]  though. It should output [{'date': '00.00.00', 'msg': '.00.00 :  Blabla\n\n'}] (This is the first line) and then [{'date': '00.00.00', 'msg': '.00.00 :  Blabla\nx\n'}] (second line)   My point is, the lines which are true are normally parsed under the rules but the ones which doesnt (false) have to be appended to the previous, which was true. Thats the tricky part. I will post the full code here.

Comment: I edited the code once more now it only outputs one line

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
path = "file.txt"
with open (path, 'r') as f:
    msg = dict()
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0].isdigit():
            tmp = line.split(':')
            date = tmp[0].strip()
            msg[date] = ' '.join(*[x.split() for x in tmp[1:]])
        else:
            msg[date] += ' ' + ' '.join(*[line.split()])
```

We go line by line, in case first letter of the line is a digit we assume it is a date and add it to our dict - otherwise we add the string found to the last dict entry we made. `str.split()` makes sure you get ride of all different whitespace characters.

You can for sure replace the if statement in the for loop with your regex... The issue i see with your implementation in general is that as soon as the input varies slightly (e.g. more whitespace chars as intended) your solution produces faulty results. Basic python string manipulations are really powerful ;)

**Update**

This should produce the right output:

```
*file.txt*
00.00.00 : Blabla
x
00.00.00 : Blabla2
x2


path = "file.txt"
with open (path, 'r') as f:
    lst = list()
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0].isdigit():
            tmp = line.split(':')
            date = tmp[0].strip()
            msg = {date: ' '.join(*[x.split() for x in tmp[1:]])}
            lst.append(msg)
        else:
            msg[date] += ' ' + ' '.join(*[line.split()])

print(lst)
>>> [{'00.00.00': 'Blabla x'}, {'00.00.00': 'Blabla2 x2'}]
```

I missed the part that you want to store each pair separately in a dict and append it to a list.

Comment: hmm I could try that but your first join is taking 2 args there right? join takes only one though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 2 args. `str.join()` works also if the list consists only of one element, e.g. `' '.join(*[x.split() for x in ['hello']])`

Comment: you are right, it does treat one elemt lists. Just tested your suggestion, it might work! I will adapt to my code and update this.

Comment: Doesnt work as I expected. As soon as another Xs come in other lines it skips them. e.g:

cat file.txt
00.00.00 :  Blabla
x
00.00.00 :  Blabla2
x2

output:
{'00.00.00': 'Blabla1'}
{'00.00.00': 'Blabla2'}
{'00.00.00': 'Blabla2 x2 '}

Comment: What is the '00.00.00' standing for? Can there be more than one pair with the same '00.00.00'?

Comment: Would be really useful if u give us one proper input example with different special cases and not making them up one by one afterwards